# use of "to" after "helping one"

Tags: grammar

What is correct:

> helping one to accomplish the dreams?

OR

> helping one accomplish the dreams?

The question I have is about the use of ***to*** in the first sentence?

Comment: Either is fine, although you normally wouldn't write “the dreams.” In this context, something like “one's dreams” would usually be preferred.

Comment: _Help_ is one of the "small verbs" (like _go, come, make, let_) that allow infinitive complements without the infinitive _to_ complementizer; or, if you prefer, which allow the infinitive _to_ complementizer to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, either way works. To can be used as and Adverb or a preposition, according to Merriam-Webster. In your first sentence, to answers the question "How is it accomplished?" Adverbs answer a variety of questions, like when, where, why, how, and to what extent. So, either sentence can be used just fine and it is understood the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Ask help? I try to use another English rule to answer this. One-has-to-help accomplish  not One-has-help accomplish , so I would use "helping one to accomplish the dream".